# MySQL join more than 3 table

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch events based on interested user location and also leave events in which user not interested. I have also try but not getting exact event data.
According to this query, if no record present in the uninterested_event table, no record fetch from tables.

```
> SELECT * FROM `event` e JOIN `user_interested_location` uil ON
> e.`city` = uil.`city` AND uil.`user_id` = 'A' JOIN
> `uninterested_event` ue ON e.`event_id` != ue.`event`
> AND ue.`user_id` = 'A' WHERE e.`start_date` >= '2018-04-14' ORDER BY
> e.`start_date` ASC



--------------------
    Event table
--------------------

event_id  | event_name | city   | start_date
event_1   |   event1   | kanpur |  2018-04-15
event_2   |   event2   | Noida  |  2018-04-20
event_3   |   event3   | Delhi  |  2018-04-14
event_4   |   event4   | Kanpur |  2018-04-17


--------------------------------
 user_interested_location table
--------------------------------

user_id  |  city   | 
   A     |  kanpur |
   B     |  Noida  |
   A     |  Noida  |


-----------------------------
 uninterested_event table
-----------------------------

user_id  | event_id | 
   A     |  event_1 |
   B     |  event_2 |


 ------------------------------
      output (user_id for A)
 ------------------------------

event_id  |  user_id   | city   | start_date
event_4   |   event4   | Kanpur | 2018-04-17
event_2   |   event2   | Noida  | 2018-04-20
```

Comment: insufficient details, Where is **uninterested_event** table data ? Please add complete details in your question

Comment: If your **user_interested_location** contains the interested location details then remaining are the not interested then why do you want to use **uninterested_event ** table ?

Comment: Too many unknowns, please extract a [mcve].

Comment: please check this, i have updated.

Comment: if user is not interested in that event which comes in interested location.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your table structure and data is not matching

Comment: Please fiddle if you need answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` e
left JOIN `user_interested_location` uil ON e.`city` = uil.`city` AND uil.`user_id` = 'A' 
left JOIN `uninterested_event` ue ON e.`event_id` = ue.`event` and ue.`user_id` = 'A'
WHERE e.`start_date` >= '2018-04-14' and ue.user_id is null
ORDER BY e.`start_date` ASC
```